# How to make snapper-boot.service create snapshots for all configs?

Tags: systemd, btrfs, snapper

I have a btrfs setup with multiple subvolumes mounted to different places of the file system. Each subvolume has a configuration for snapper:

> cat /etc/conf.d/snapper

```
[...]
SNAPPER_CONFIGS="root home [...]"
```

The service for creating snapshots on boot is defined in the file

> cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/snapper-boot.service

```
[...]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/snapper --config root --cleanup-algorithm number --description "boot"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/snapper --config home --cleanup-algorithm number --description "boot"
[...]
```

**Instead of adding one line per subvolume**, which is error-prone, I'd like to **read the list of snapper configurations and iterate**.

Is this possible?

Is it advisable?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible to implement that.

A simple way would be to use a shell script that would call `snapper` repeatedly, once for each config. A `for` loop would be enough to do that, it seems.

You can even do it inline in the systemd unit file:

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -e -c '. /etc/conf.d/snapper; for conf in $$SNAPPER_CONFIGS; do /usr/bin/snapper --config "$$conf" --cleanup-algorithm number --description "boot"; done'
```

Note that you need to escape the `$`s, so that systemd doesn't try to interpret those as systemd variables and instead lets the shell interpret them. (In my opinion, using an external shell script that you call in `ExecStart=` is a cleaner approach, then you don't need to deal with escaping and don't need to cram everything into a single line either.)

Another option would be to modify `snapper` itself so it could handle that natively. Say, make it read that config file and handle those configs whenever it's called without any `--config` arguments. That would be an even cleaner approach.

Whether it's advisable or not... I guess it depends. If you're getting this `snapper-boot.sevice` unit from a package from your distribution, then you might have trouble whenever there's a package upgrade that would touch that file. So, in a way, it depends on your particular situation.

If this unit file is indeed shipped with a package from your Linux distribution, you might want to consider opening a bug report to them, asking them to avoid hardcoding config names in the unit file.

If it's not owned by your distribution, then consider storing it in `/etc/systemd/system` instead, since the `/usr/lib` is typically reserved for files shipped and managed by the Linux distribution.

Comment: Regarding the ownership of /usr/lib/systemd/system/snapper-boot.service:
You said that it was inadvisable to change this file, if it is managed by the package management system. On my Arch system, this is the case (verify by executing "pacman -Ql snapper | grep snapper-boot").
Therefore i'll take your advice to create a new file in /etc/systemd/system.

Comment: @Archibald Take a look at command `systemctl edit`, which is meant to create overrides for the unit files shipped with your distribution.

Comment: @Archibald You might want to file a bug report/feature request with Arch Linux too... Since this seems like a config duplication/limitation of their setup, they might want to address it there as well.

Comment: I suggested the iteration feature to the snapper project here:
https://github.com/openSUSE/snapper/issues/450